# Auto generated FAQs - Does "unnamed item" in schema hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, schema.org

I'm using FAQ schema in a collection list template, so dynamic tags for the Question and Answer.  On pages without FAQ my page still contains the schema script but without any content. It's therefore showing as an error rather than acting in a spammy way - it's not showing anything that's not on the page as the tags are empty.  On other pages the tags pull through Q&A where I've entered the information.

Is it fine to leave the empty script on those page without FAQ, or should I create an exclusion for those empty pages to prevent it from being created in the first place?

Some of the questions are auto-filled by our customers but sometimes they are empty and not yet prepopulated.

[image]

Comment: Schema has almost nothing to do with SEO, see [SEO Myth: Structured data helps search engine rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/structured-data-seo/).   The only way it helps SEO is when you get a rich snippet and the only way it hurts is when you get a penalty for abusing it.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! Google doesn't recognize Name itemProp values in structured data for FAQs, Logos, Sitelinks searchbox, and likely others. Why their testing tools always return 'Unnamed' for these itempTypes is a mystery.

Edit: Name for the Question is required and Google will not accept its value being blank: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/faqpage

Comment: What does `itemProp` have to do with it?   There are blank `name` and `text` values in the example that was given.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought he was talking about the Name for the FAQ item itself, not the name of the individual Questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an exclusion for those empty pages to prevent it from being created in the first place.

It would be misleading to use `"@Type": "FAQPage"` on a page that doesn't have FAQs. I would make sure that your other types of pages are either getting either `Article`, `BlogPosting`, or `NewsArticle` (if a post) or simply `WebPage` (for a regular page).

Will keeping the empty `FAQPage` markup tank your visibility?

Definitely not.

Would it be best practice?

No.